# Using Pandas Autocorrelation Plot - how to limit x-axis to make it more readable?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, autocorrelation

I am using python 3.7.

I am performing time series forecasting using an ARIMA model. I am assessing the properties of my data for ARIMA using an Autocorrelation Plot - specifically using autocorrelation_plot from pandas.plotting.

My data has 50,000 records or so, making the plot extremely busy and hard to pick out any specific trends. Is there a way to limit the x-axis to bring the first few hundred lags more into focus?

I can't share the actual plot, but my code is as follow:

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas.plotting import autocorrelation_plot

#Import Data
time_series_2619 = pd.read_csv("Consumption/2619.csv", parse_dates=['Date/Time'], index_col = ['Date/Time'])['Recording']

#Auto Correlation Plot
autocorrelation_plot(time_series_2619)
```

I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`autocorrelation_plot` returns a matplotlib.axis object. Hence, you can simply use the `set_xlim()` method to limit the x-axis:

```
ax = autocorrelation_plot(time_series_2619)
ax.set_xlim([0, 500])
```

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you can use the `plot_acf()` function and specify the lags.

```
# import the plotting functions for act and pacf  
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf, plot_pacf
plot_acf(df1['Thousands of Passengers'], lags=40);
```

Comment: Heavily underrated, especially if your time series is large enough.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add another way of plotting the autocorrelation, which to be honest is much faster in small-data cases:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
plt.title('Autocorrelation plot')
plt.plot(np.arange(720), [time_series_2619['column_name'].autocorr(j) for j in range(720)])
plt.show();
```

You are just using the `Series.autocorr()` function of a pandas series, which needs a lag number and returns the autocorrelation between the two timestamps. Doing a simple comprehension list you will be able to have an array of autocorrelations, which can be plotted easily using pyplot.